# aws code deploy disables github revision option

Tags: github, aws-code-deploy

I wanted to deploy my code in github using codedeploy but the option "My application is stored in GitHub" is disabled. why is it disabled? and how can I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Reading "[GitHub Behaviors with [AWS] CodeDeploy](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-partners-github.html#github-behaviors)", it may be a permission issue:

> After you give CodeDeploy permission to interact with GitHub, the association between that GitHub account and application is stored in CodeDeploy.
> You can link the application to a different GitHub account. You can also revoke permission for CodeDeploy to interact with GitHub.

Double-check the steps described in "[Create an EC2/On-Premises Compute Platform Deployment (Console)](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-codedeploy-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/deployments-create-console.md)"

For instance:

> Your application must have a deployment group before it can be deployed. If your application does not have a deployment group, on the Deployment groups tab, choose Create deployment group.
> For more information, see Create a [Deployment Group with CodeDeploy](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-codedeploy-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/deployment-groups-create.md).